# MacOS - killall "mongrel_rails" says "No matching processes belonging to you were found"

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, kill

I have five instances of mongrel_rails running, under my username ('max'):

```
$ ps aux | grep mongrel_rails
max              32500  98.8  0.2 10061608  34112 s007  R    12:52pm  13:47.15 mongrel_rails [3003/1/0]: handling 127.0.0.1: GET /music_service_admin
max              32497  98.4 10.6 10085244 1779008 s007  R    12:52pm   8:11.85 mongrel_rails [3000/1/1]: handling 127.0.0.1: GET /music_service_admin
max              34449   0.0  0.0 408103312   1360 s009  S+    1:07pm   0:00.00 grep mongrel_rails
max              32501   0.0 14.2 10035048 2388400 s007  S+   12:52pm   0:39.37 mongrel_rails [3004/0/3]: idle
max              32499   0.0 12.6 10035060 2108720 s007  S    12:52pm   0:39.72 mongrel_rails [3002/0/3]: idle
max              32498   0.0 12.5 10031968 2096576 s007  S    12:52pm   0:32.58 mongrel_rails [3001/0/2]: idle
```

`killall` doesn't want to let me kill them:

```
$ killall mongrel_rails
No matching processes belonging to you were found

$ sudo killall mongrel_rails
Password:
No matching processes were found
```

I've recently switched to mac from linux, for development.  In linux this worked fine, what's the problem here, can anyone see?

I can kill the individual processes, with eg `kill -9 32500`, but i want to call killall from a script.

Answer (score 2):

```
pkill -f {process_name}
```

and if you have permission denied just add:

```
sudo pkill -f {process_name}
```

Comment: thanks - that seems like a good approach, but when I tried it it failed to kill two of them.  Interestingly, the reason I wanted to kill them in the first place was that two of them had got "stuck" on something, and it's those two that aren't being killed.